# Collapsing rows on condition and re-using their values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have quite a simple problem, which appearently does not have a quite-so-simple solution. Assume I have the following data:

```
> test <- data.frame(Day = c(1:10), Counts = c(0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0, 3, 4))
> test
   Day Counts
1    1      0
2    2      0
3    3      6
4    4      0
5    5      0
6    6      5
7    7      1
8    8      0
9    9      3
10  10      4
```

From knowledge on the origin of the data I can safely assume that the non-zero *Counts* would not occur on subsequent days. Rather, some of the *Counts* were missed on the original *Day*. For example, the *Counts* of *Day* 6 and 7 would belong to *Day* 6 (with 6 *Counts* in total).

I'd like to find a routine solution which could produce this desired output:

```
  Day Counts
1   1      0
2   2      0
3   3      6
4   4      0
5   5      0
6   6      6
7   8      0
8   9      7
```

Notice how *Day*s 7 and 10 have been removed, and their *Counts* have been added to those of *Day*s 6 and 9. This is indeed the format I need for subsequent analysis of the data, which would be compromised by the "false" *Counts*.

I already tried multiple "moving/rolling window" approaches with functions from the `zoo` and `RcppRoll` packages, as well as so-called **tidy** solution using `dplyr`s `lag()`and `lead()` functions, but no Heureka! thus far. As my data set contains hundred thousands of rows (and a lot more columns), a manual correction is highly undesirable.

Any help is appreciated! Even if it's just pointing to an existing question...

p.s.: Bonus points for showing a **tidyverse** solution, as I intend on using this in a pipe workflow.

**EDIT**: Thanks for the solutions, they both work perfectly! Made my day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lead` and `lag` are certainly one way to do it.

```
test %>%
  mutate(lead1 = lead(Counts, 1), lag1 = lag(Counts)) %>% 
  mutate(Counts2 = if_else(Counts > 0, Counts + lead1, Counts)) %>% 
  filter(!(lag1 > 0 & Counts > 0))
```

The code can be shortened to

```
test %>%
  mutate(Counts = if_else(Counts > 0, Counts + lead(Counts, 1), Counts)) %>% 
  filter(!(lag(Counts) > 0 & Counts > 0))

  Day Counts
1   1      0
2   2      0
3   3      6
4   4      0
5   5      0
6   6      6
7   8      0
8   9      7
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple dplyr approach based on `lag` and `lead`:

```
test %>%
  mutate(Counts = ifelse(Counts != 0 & lead(Counts) != 0,
                         Counts + lead(Counts), Counts)) %>%
  mutate(Counts = ifelse(Counts != 0 & lag(Counts) != 0, NA, Counts)) %>%
  na.omit()
  Day Counts
1   1      0
2   2      0
3   3      6
4   4      0
5   5      0
6   6      6
8   8      0
9   9      7
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** This uses the data.table package. First convert test to a data.table `dt` and then create a grouping variable using `rleid` which creates a group for each run of zeros or non-zeros.  For each such group return the sum of the counts followed by trailing zeros:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(test)

dt[, Fix := c(sum(Counts), 0 * Counts[-1]), by = rleid(Counts > 0)]
```

giving:

```
> dt
    Day Counts Fix
 1:   1      0   0
 2:   2      0   0
 3:   3      6   6
 4:   4      0   0
 5:   5      0   0
 6:   6      5   6
 7:   7      1   0
 8:   8      0   0
 9:   9      3   7
10:  10      4   0
```

**2)** This uses dplyr with `rleid` from data.table:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

test %>%
     group_by(rleid(Counts > 0)) %>%
     mutate(Fix = c(sum(Counts), 0 * Counts[-1])) %>%
     ungroup
```